# Read-only class properties

Tags: object-oriented, encapsulation, immutability, properties

When is recommended to use `read-only` properties -- if the language allows me?

Are *public* read-only properties meant to replace `getter` methods or at least the *Magic Methods* like what is available as [__get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) in PHP for example?

What is the use of a *private* read-only property?

Comment: To add to @Uri Agassi's answer, the `readonly` property which is available in C# (and possibly languages?) is similar to Java's `final` which can be applied to member fields to ensure that they are set during object construction and never changed.

Comment: @gnat: How is that a duplicate?  This question asks about the use of read-only properties, that one asks about immutability?

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you think it should be closed as [too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) instead?

Comment: It's a bit broad, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read-only` properties are assigned only once - on the initialization of the instance.

It is different from `getters`, since `getters` allow the instance itself to change the value of the property. It is different from constants, since constants are assigned on the class declaration.

One use-case for read-only properties is to define immutable objects, another is in the definition of `static read-only` for a singleton implementation.

Other use-cases may be in container properties (like lists and dictionaries), in which it is intended that their *contents* might change, but the collection itself stays with the instance for all its life-cycle. This way you can be sure that they are never nullified.

These are some use-cases of the top of my head, I'm sure that there are more...

Comment: Great! I was totally wrong about them then, thanks a lot!

Comment: how about "any time a property reflects something distinct about a class whose meaning would be invalid were it changed", like a "FileReader" object's "FilePath" property.

Comment: @DougM I love your example!